# Visual Basic Word Get Elements from a Website

Tags: vba, ms-word, web

I'm trying to import text from specific div´s of a website to a bookmark in a Word document and I'm stuck with reading the HTML from a website. I tried 100 tutorials all for VBA Excel (maybe that's why) and always the same result.

Let's say that I have a site like:

```
<html>
 <div id = "test">
  this is an example text
 </div>
</html>
```

and here is my VBA Code:

```
Sub read_html()
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

Dim htmlOut As String
    With objIE
        .Navigate "http://blabla.net/testy/test.html"
        Do
        Loop Until Not .Busy
        htmlOut = .Document.getElementsByName("test")
        .Quit
    MsgBox "example:" & htmlOut
    End With
Set iexpl = Nothing
End Sub
```

The MsgBox returns: example [object]

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByName will return a collection of all the elements with that name. Even if there's only one, it still returns a collection. Just a collection with one item in it. You can get the first element in the collection like

```
htmlOut = .Document.getElementsByName("test").Item(0).InnerText
```

The .Item(0) will return the first item and the .InnerText will return a string.